# Copying files in multiple subdirectories in the Linux command line

Tags: linux, cp

Let's say I have the following subdirectories

```
./a/, ./b/, ./c/, ...
```

That is, in my current working directory are these subdirectories `a/`, `b/` and `c/`, and in each of these subdirectories are files. In directory `a/` is the file `a.in`, in directory `b/` is the file `b.in` and so forth.

I now want to copy each `.in` file to a `.out` file, that is, `a.in` to `a.out` and `b.in` to `b.out`, and I want them to reside in the directories they were copied from. So `a.out` will be found in directory `a/`.

I've tried various different approaches, such as

```
find ./ -name '*.in'|cp * *.out
```

which doesn't work because it thinks `*.out` is a directory. Also tried

```
ls -d */ | cd; cp *.in *.out
```

but it that would list the subdirectories, go into each one of them, but won't let `cp` do it's work (which still doesn't work)

The

```
find ./ -name '*.in'
```

command works fine. Is there a way to pipe arguments to an assignment operator? E.g.

```
find ./ -name '*.in'| assign filename=|cp filename filename.out
```

where `assign filename=` gives filename the value of each `.in` file. In fact, it would be even better if the assignment could get rid of the `.in` file extension, then instead of getting `a.in.out` we would get the preferred `a.out`

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let the shell help you out:

```
find . -name '*.in' | while read old; do
    new=${old%.in}.out # strips the .in and adds .out
    cp "$old" "$new"
done
```

I just took the find command you said works and let bash read its output one filename at a time.  So the bash while loop gets the filenames one at a time, does a little substitution, and a straight copy.  Nice and easy (but not tested!).

Comment: This is a great use of while and read - and will succeed with larger sets of files than the for loop in my answer...

Comment: Do you mean that 'old' is the variable the find command spits out? And you can actually loop through this variable? Is this a shell script, or can I write this directly to the cli?

Comment: `old` is the variable set by the `read` command which is in turn executed for each line from `find` by the `while` loop.  You can paste it into the CLI if you want, that's the same as writing it in a script file.  Just replace the newlines with semicolons if you want it on one line (and maybe get rid of the `new` variable and the comment).

Comment: @Kyle: Poor while-read, nobody remembers to use it (or maybe nobody remembers that you can pipe together things that aren't programs).

Comment: It doesn't exit the loop. I have to break it with Ctrl-C

Comment: Does it ever enter the loop?  Maybe your version of find has the path part mandatory (I left it out, since my find assumes .).

Comment: Yes, I did add the path to the `find` command, like this: 

    `find ./ -name '*.in' | (...)`

Answer (score 1):

Try a for loop:

```
for f in */*.in; do
    cp $f ${f%.in}.out;
done
```

The glob should catch all the files one directory down that have a .in extension.  In the cp command, it strips off the .in suffix and then appends a .out (see [Variable Mangling in Bash with String Operators](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8919))

Alternatively, if you want to recurse into every subdirectory (not just 1 level deep) replace the glob with a find:

```
for f in $(find . -name '*.in'); do
    cp $f ${f%.in}.out;
done
```

Comment: In the error message it omits all the directories, and tells me finally that the *.in doesn't exist: "No such file or directory

Comment: That's correct, this will only work if run from a directory as you described in your question.  The examples using find will work when no files are found.

Comment: I am running this from the parent directory.

Comment: what do you get if you do echo */*.in?  If I understand what you're saying, that should result in a list of all the files 1 directory beneath the current who's names end in .in

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick!

```
for f in `find . -type f -name "*.in"`; do cp $f `echo $f | sed 's/in$/out/g'`; done
```

Comment: The many invocations of `sed` there are quite unnecessary.  Just use bash's variable substitution to do the name mangling.